How can I ensure batch processing with a minimum size in RabbitMQ in a stateless environment?
I'm working with a system that generates thousands of events per minute, and I need to consume these events in batches of N, ensuring that the batch has a minimum size before processing. Specifically, I want to process these events in bulk to insert them into a database efficiently.
The challenge is that the consumer runs in a stateless environment, so I can't manually manage an array or buffer to accumulate messages. I need RabbitMQ to only trigger processing when the batch has accumulated at least N messages, or after a timeout if the minimum size isn't reached.
I've experimented with setting the prefetch_count in RabbitMQ, but this only guarantees a maximum number of unacknowledged messages, not a minimum batch size before invoking the consumer. I’ve also tried working with RabbitMQ streams and managing the offset manually, but that approach doesn't seem to provide a reliable solution either.
Is there a way to achieve this kind of minimum batch size behavior natively in RabbitMQ, either through configurations or plugins? If not, what tool would allow me to handle high-frequency event streams with a minimum batch size requirement in a stateless environment?
